# Separating GEO database from normal database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geo

Currently I have 2 databases

1. Primary (default) database, containing everything like users, posts etc. (this one runs on PostgreSQL wie psycopg2)
2. Secondary (geo) database, containing only geo data (this one runs on postgis 1.5)

Django and PG do not support cross-database relations for good reasons, I already know that, but I split my databases up, because I fear that the geo database is optimised for geo data and if I mix all data in one database the whole performance will suffer from this, plus I don't even know if I can have everyting in one database geo and normal data.
But I want to relate data from the primary(1) database to the secondary(2) database.

Is this approach reasonable or is it completely wrong to split it up?

Comment: If you want to join data from two tables they have to be on the same database or it won't work.

Comment: @Patashu I know that. And I won't need to join custom data only relations. E.g. A ist on (1) and B ist on (2). B is a geo entry related to A. A.get_B() could easily issue a query on database (2) passing A's primary key which is just a bigint on B's table but indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, it is obvious that the data needs to be in one database.

Spatial isn't special, it's just another data type. I don't see why enabling PostGIS would compromise the performance of a database. However, it doesn't hurt to test this with a copy of the primary database, particularly for production environments.

If you are concerned that enabling PostGIS will add hundreds of functions to the "public" schema, you can make a "postgis" schema and put the extension there. [See these details](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/248-Moving-PostGIS-to-another-schema-with-Extensions.html). However, I'm not sure how geodjango will cope with this setup.

Comment: That link is very interesting, I would have to upgrade to PostGIS 2.0 but I don't think that this will be a major problem. I will implement a test setup today and comment on it as soon as it's done.

Comment: [Here's another resource](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43187/are-there-any-tricks-to-using-a-schema-other-than-public-in-postgis?rq=1). I recall a similar method for PostGIS 1.5, but not sure where it went to. Keep in mind that [PostGIS 1.5 is supported up to PostgreSQL 9.1](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS) (but not newer).